# Payara 5 not sending emails

Tags: email, payara

On the Payara5, I have configured a JNDI resource for JavaMail Session and have applied the following properties to the configuration on Admin Console:

JNDI Name: mail/<myApp>Email
Mail Host: mail.<myemailServer>.com
Default User: admin@<myApp>.com
Password: <valid password to the above Default User>
Auth: Enabled
Default Sender Address: admin@<myApp>.com (same as Default User)

I have also specified some "Additional Properties" as below:
mail.smtp.port = 587
mail.smtp.starttls.enable = true
mail.smtp.starttls.required =true

I my Java EJB Code, I am accessing the Mail Session as a resource:

```
@Resource(name = "mail/<myApp>Email") - same as configured on Admin console
Session session;
```

and then using it as follows:

```
 MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
 message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(sender)); - Default Sender Address in Admin Console
 message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(user.getEmail()));
 message.setSubject(<Subject>));
 message.setContent(<String Message>, "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
 Transport.send(message);
```

In spite of all this the Application generated emails are not reaching the user (user.getEmail())

Am I missing anything here?

Any response would be very much appreciated.

Singham